# Sql to for complex win query

Tags: sql

I have following table as Records

```
TeamA   | TeamB      | Winner
--------+------------+---------
Lakers  | Sacramento | Lakers
Clipper | Rockets    | Rockets
Lakers  | Suns       | Suns
```

Need to convert into table like this

```
Team   | Win | Loss | TotalMatches
Lakers |  1  |   1  |     2
........
```

I started with union but not able to progress

```
Select 
    TeamA, TeamB
from 
    Records
union
Select 
     teamA, teamB
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpivot first bu using `UNION ALL`, and then apply conditional aggregation

```
SELECT team, SUM(CASE WHEN winner = team THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Win,
             SUM(CASE WHEN winner != team THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Loss,
             COUNT(*) AS TotalMatches
  FROM ( SELECT teamA AS team, Winner FROM Records
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT teamB, Winner FROM Records ) r
 GROUP BY team
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=597f5e7f724a7baad570609621ea23b6)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION ALL to get 1 row for each team and match with the result of the match and aggregate:

```
SELECT Team, 
       SUM(result) Win,
       SUM(1 - result) Loss,
       COUNT(*) TotalMatches
FROM (
  SELECT TeamA AS Team, CASE WHEN TeamA = Winner THEN 1 ELSE 0 END result
  FROM Records
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TeamB, CASE WHEN TeamB = Winner THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
  FROM Records
) t
GROUP BY Team
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=41b8225b9d8516dcdc73dc8b92c06171) (for SQL Server but it is standard SQL).

```
> Team       | Win | Loss | TotalMatches
> :--------- | --: | ---: | -----------:
> Clipper    |   0 |    1 |            1
> Lakers     |   1 |    1 |            2
> Rockets    |   1 |    0 |            1
> Sacramento |   0 |    1 |            1
> Suns       |   1 |    0 |            1
```